# Meteor import flowRouter and IronRouter error

Tags: meteor, flow-router

I use import folder on my Meteor App, but I got error with following config :

**/imports/startup/client/routes.js**

```
import { FlowRouter } from 'meteor/kadira:flow-router';
import { BlazeLayout } from 'meteor/kadira:blaze-layout';

import '../../../ui/layout/layout.js';
import '../../../ui/pages/home/home.js';


FlowRouter.route('/', {
    action: function() {
        console.log("Yeah! We are on the post:");
    }
});
```

and my **/client/main.js**

```
import '/imports/startup/client';
```

And I've this error :

> Error: Cannot find module 'routes.js'

Do you have any idea why routes.js isn't loaded ?

Thank you !

Comment: Your code is not quite clear enough but base on the error message, I guess something is wrong when you export - import the `routes.js` module. Have you *really* export the module ? Is the provided relative path correct ?

Comment: Yep, relative path is correct, i've test :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the routes file. Your current import resolves to a folder so it will import the index file in the folder if there is one.